# Counting number of rectangles of odd area

Tags: combinatorics

There is a rectangular sheet of dimensions $(2m-1)\times(2n-1)$,where $m>0,~n>0$.  It has been divided into squares of unit area by drawing lines perpendicular to the sides. Find number of rectangles having both sides of odd unit length

The problem gives these multiple choice answers:

1. $(m+n+1)^2$
2. $mn(m+1)(n+1)$
3. $4^m+n-2$
4. $(mn)^2$

Comment: $M \neq m$.  Please be consistent.  Have you tried counting by hand for small $m$?  You are just looking for the number of ways to pick two points on each side that are an odd distance apart.

Comment: I strongly discourage the use of the word "permutations" as a blanket term for counting problems in combinatorics.  Permutations are a *very specific* type of combinatorial object to count sometimes described as bijective functions from a set to itself and other times as an arrangement of distinct letters such that all letters appear exactly once, and these certainly aren't permutations.  Use a more general description for the problem: it falls under the category of *combinatorics* (*or more specifically enumerative combinatorics*).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  For the rectangle to have odd length on both sides, the height must be odd and the width must be odd.  For simplicity's sake, lets call the height axis the $y$-axis and the width axis the $x$-axis and let us have the bottom left corner of our $(2m-1)\times(2n-1)$ sheet be the origin.

For the height to be odd of our selected rectangle, the $y$ coordinate of the bottom and top must be of different parity (*i.e. one must be odd and the other must be even*).  Consequently, any selection of an even $y$-coordinate and an odd $y$-coordinate will correspond to a way of picking the height and distance away from the bottom edge of the sheet for our selected rectangle.

- How many ways are there to select one odd $y$-coordinate and one even $y$-coordinate?

(*Be careful about counting how many even coordinates there are and how many odd coordinates there are available*)

> $n$ ways to pick the even coordinate and $n$ ways to pick the odd coordinate.  Applying multiplication principle then, there are $n^2$ ways to pick one of each.

Apply a similar thought process for the width.  Finish the problem by applying multiplication principle and recognizing that any rectangle can be described uniquely via its odd $x$-coordinate, odd $y$-coordinate, even $x$-coordinate, even $y$-coordinate selections.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for sharing it with us.

Answer (score 0):

The number of all rectangles= $\displaystyle{2m\choose 2}{2n\choose 2}$

The number of rectangles with even width = $\displaystyle2{m\choose 2}{2n\choose 2}$

The number of rectangles with even height = $\displaystyle 2{n\choose 2}{2m\choose 2}$

The number of rectangles with both even width and height = $\displaystyle 2{m\choose 2}2{n\choose 2}$

So the answer is (use PIE):

$${2m\choose 2}{2n\choose 2}-2{m\choose 2}{2n\choose 2}-2{n\choose 2}{2m\choose 2} + 4{m\choose 2}{n\choose 2}= m^2n^2$$

Comment: There is a *much* cleaner way of thinking about the problem which doesn't require the use of binomial coefficients.

Comment: Trying to parse what it is you've written.  I believe you made a few small mistakes.  The theory is fine but check the following things: If something is of *length* $(2m-1)$, how many grid points are on it (*don't forget to think about zero*).  Secondly, the expression should be symmetric about $m$ and $n$, it appears you have a mistaken $m$ as a typo at the tail end.

Comment: I'll say it again a different way.  How many odd-area rectangles are there in the case that $n=m=1$, i.e. in a $(2m-1)\times(2n-1)$ rectangle, i.e. in a $1\times 1$ rectangle (*it shouldn't be zero*).  You should also correct the phrase "*The number of rectangles with one even side*" to be "*The number of rectangles with even width*" and include only half of the expression that follows since the expression that you wrote is instead actually equal to the number of rectangles of even width plus the number with even height (*which is strictly more than rectangles with an even side*).